# How to give inline css in reacts class component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to give inline css in reacts class component.

I have a css something like this.

```
{
    font-size: 17px;           
font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
    color: #565656;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
}
```

Now when I am reading this css from the css file this is working fine but my css class is coming from library so writing there is not accessible. So How can I make it inline.

Working

```
 <div style= {{border :"1px solid #ced4da", overflow : "auto",height : "300px"}}>
```

Not working

```
<div style= {{font-size: 17px, font-family: Segoe UI Semibold, color: #565656 ,text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;}}>
```

Inline css only apply as  camel case so how to over come with this. What is an alternate for this.

Comment: https://styled-components.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add hyphens in inline-css
so you need to change the div element to

```
<div style= {{fontSize: "17px", fontFamily: "Segoe UI Semibold", color: "#565656" ,textShadow: "0 1px 1px white"}}>
```

Comment: oh yes, I was not thinking like that, was trying for same css as it is in css class. Thanks @Vihaanverma27